# Dynamic URL generation for site sections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am thinking about having different site sections of a Rails 3 webapp. The site sections should show the same resources using the same controller and the same views.

So `http://foo.org/premium/products/1` should present the same product as `http://foo.org/products/1` (maybe with some modifications dependent on the section).

For handling that I thought about rewriting the URL somehow (maybe in routes.rb, at the Rack level or the server level), so that `http://foo.org/premium/products/1` becomes `http://foo.org/products/1?section=premium`. Are there any better solutions for that?

But the real problem I see is when generating the links of those sites as those should retain the section. E.g. a link on the site `http://foo.org/premium/products/1` to the product with id 2 should be `http://foo.org/premium/products/2` and not `http://foo.org/products/2?section=premium`.

Unfortunately this is not so trivial as link_to and *_path don't know about the sections. I also want to make this highly dynamic so that I can easily add and remove sections without touching static routes.

I thought about rewriting the URLs after they were generated by `link_to`. Would this be a good approach? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I chose the approach of rewriting the URLs as there are only minor changes between those site sections (e.g. another background). That way I could reuse all MVC classes instead of creating new stuff when using for example routing namespaces.

For rewriting the URLs I use Rack middlewares. All incoming URLs are rewritten by [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite/). Links of the response body are rewritten by another custom middleware (something like done in this [Railscasts transcript](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware).

So URLs like `/premium/products/1` will end up as `/products/1?section=premium` (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

If the only difference between the routes is the addition of `premium` then that would be a [namespace approach](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a namespace (as @jpx777 said), your project structure should look like this:

```
app/
+controllers/
++premium/
+++products_controller.rb
++products_controller.rb
+views/
++premium/
+++products/
++++...(premium product related views)
++products/
+++...(product related views)
```

And in your routes.rb:

```
namespace "premium" do
  resources :products
end
resources :products
```

Comment: Ok, it seems my question wasn't clear enough (I update it). The namespace approach uses a new controller and other views. What I want is to reuse the same controller and views, just an alias URL to access it (and an option to get the alias inside the controller). But I want `link_to` retain the current alias URL.

Comment: I still think that namespace is the best way to do this. Are you worried about keeping things DRY? If that's the case, you could use partials in your views, and create a module that could be included in each controller. That way you'd be prepared for any necessary changes that may happen in the layout or even in the controller. Otherwise you will be hacking every time a difference between premium and non-premium appears.

Comment: Yes, it is a DRY problem I see here. I have to use a view variation for each site section as I also have different paths (e.g. `premium_products_path`, `producsts_path`). If I want to resuse partials or complete views then I will end up again checking in which section I am currently and then calling `link_to` with the correct path. Or do I miss something?

Comment: You could pass the correct path as a parameter to the partial: `render :partial => 'product', :locals => {:path => premium_products_path}` and `render :partial => 'product', :locals => {:path => products_path}`

Comment: Ok, that would work, but still having some doubts ;-) The thing is that I only have to do minor changes between those sections. But it seems that there isn't a perfect solution.